# Remove selectable text from source code PDF output

Tags: graphics, minted

I am writing my master thesis in LaTeX. For source code listings I use `minted` package. However, my thesis supervisor pointed out that the anti-plagiarism software that is now used in my country will pick up code snippets and mark them as  plagiarism (which is unavoidable since a lot of the code is in GLSL shader language and thus looks like all other shader programs). He makes his students insert source code as pictures from IDE.

So, I am looking for a way to either:

1. convert `minted` output to images during LaTeX build
2. I'm not sure if this would work, but I was also wondering if I could somehow strip "text" information from PDF file for source codes so they would appear on printed pages but would not be selectable/copyable (the anti-plagiarism system converts everything to TXT before processing)

BTW, some code span multiple pages so it can't be as easy as one listing-one picture.

Comment: To appear on printed pages without the underlying textual content it would not help to import say pdf pages of your minted text. Your supervisor may not always be right but with their experience have learnt that images is the way to go. IT IS frustrating to clip the minted output . You could save block as subfiles for draft run as tex includes to let you approximate line cuts then print each compiled sub file to image pdf for replace one tex include with one to three \includegraphics so as to fit each page but after a few attempts it should become second nature as to how many lines will fit.

Comment: How does it handle normal quotes (with credit given)?