# Minted; make text non selectable on output pdf?

Tags: minted

### Context:

I want to build a coding exercice for some people.
I use minted to render code.
I don't want people to copy/paste the code but to write it down instead.

### Question:

How could I say to minted to make the code text 'non selectable' with the mouse on the output PDF?

Here is the minted documentation: http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf
I can't find any way to do that this documentation.

### Example:

Here is an example of minted code I use:

```
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
\begin{minted}[frame=single,
  escapeinside=||,
  mathescape,
  %bgcolor=lbcolor,
  linenos,
  numbersep=5pt,
  fontsize=\small,
  framesep=1mm]{python3}
some code here
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

### Environment:

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit (5.4.0-42-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux).

Thanks.

Comment: Would an option be just to convert it to am image (using the `standalone` document class for example) and embedding the image into your document?

Comment: Your question looks exactly like this one, but it doesn't have any answers. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477693

Comment: You could convert the text to shapes with Ghostscript using `gs -o file-with-outlines.pdf -dNoOutputFonts -sDEVICE=pdfwrite file.pdf`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797418/replace-all-font-glyphs-in-a-pdf-by-converting-them-to-outline-shapes. Note that this will apply to all the text in the document, not only the `minted` parts.

Comment: This last comment is a nice workaround, but then all normal text is no more "searchable" in the document, which is annoying if one want to search a specific word outside the parts containing code. And URL ou any other links are then broken.